# How to edit and delete drupal 8 custom block content?

Tags: blocks, 8

I am not getting any option to edit my custom block body content and not able to delete also.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visit your block library, there's a tab on blocks page.

Block library can be found here: 
/admin/structure/block/block-content

Comment: Thank you , Now i am able to edit the block but after delete a block it still display in block layout page.